# How to get total sum from one table with inner join in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables one is orders and second is order_product in which I have to find out orders count, product count, totalamount in corresponding to
customer using buyers id from which I have successfully find out the orders count and product count but my totalamount is not coming correct.

**orders:**

```
.......................................
 order_id   or_buyer_id   or_total_amt
.......................................
    1           21           10
    2           22           10
    3           21           10
```

**order_product**

```
.................................
op_id  op_order_id  op_buyer_id
.................................
  1       1          21
  2       1          21
  3       2          22
  4       3          21
```

I want below output but my totalamount value is coming wrong it is coming
30,but the correct value is 20 which i have mentioned in the right output below.

output which i want:

```
............................................
or_buyer_id  orders  product   totalmount
...........................................
   21         2       3          20
   22         1       1          10
```

I have tried the below query which is giving 30 value of totalamount which is wrong.

```
SELECT o.or_buyer_id
     , count(DISTINCT o.order_id) as orders
     , count(op.op_id) as product
     , SUM(o.or_total_amt) as totalamount 
  FROM orders as o
  JOIN order_product as op 
    on op.op_order_id = o.order_id 
   and o.or_buyer_id = op.op_buyer_id 
 group 
    by o.or_buyer_id
```

Comment: Please show some queries to return some relevant data. Please read & act on [ask] & [mcve] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to remove the duplicate rows from the `order_product` table in a subquery.  Then, join that to `orders` as you were already doing.  One slight trick here is that we maintain the number of original records in the `order_product` table when removing duplicates in the subquery.  This is because the `product` column reflects the true original record count.  But the `totalamount` does not reflect duplicates, hence we sum this quantity with duplicates removed.

```
SELECT
    t1.op_buyer_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t1.op_order_id) AS orders,
    SUM(t1.cnt) AS product,
    SUM(t2.or_total_amt) AS totalamount
FROM
(
    SELECT op_order_id, op_buyer_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM order_product
    GROUP BY op_order_id, op_buyer_id
) t1
INNER JOIN orders t2
    ON t1.op_order_id = t2.order_id AND
       t1.op_buyer_id = t2.or_buyer_id
GROUP BY
    t1.op_buyer_id
ORDER BY
    t1.op_buyer_id;
```

[image: screen capture of demo query]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You should use a subquery in the inner join instead of referring directly to order_product table:

Try to substitute order_product with

```
(SELECT DISTINCT op_order_id, op_buyer_id
 FROM order_product) AS op
```

This will remove duplicates that are giving you the wrong sum.

I also introduced a subquery to get the correct product value:

```
SELECT count(op_order_id) FROM order_product WHERE order_id = o.order_id AND op_buyer_id = o.or_buyer_id) as product
```

The final SQL is:

```
SELECT o.`or_buyer_id`, 
       count(DISTINCT o.`order_id`) as orders, 
       (SELECT count(op_order_id) FROM order_product WHERE order_id = o.order_id AND op_buyer_id = o.or_buyer_id) as product,
       SUM(o.`or_total_amt`) as totalamount 
FROM `orders` as o 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT op_order_id, 
                            op_buyer_id
            FROM order_product) AS op 
ON op.op_order_id=o.order_id AND o.or_buyer_id = op.op_buyer_id 
GROUP BY o.`or_buyer_id`
```

Comment: Hi Kiko, this query does not appear to give the correct results ([Demo](http://rextester.com/YFR46727)).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I introduced a new subquery to get the correct product field, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use this subquery

```
SELECT tbl.op_buyer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT tbl.op_order_id) AS orders, SUM(tbl.cont) AS product, SUM(tbl2.or_total_amt) AS totalamount FROM ( SELECT op_order_id, op_buyer_id, COUNT(*) AS cont FROM order_product GROUP BY op_order_id, op_buyer_id ) tbl INNER JOIN orders tbl2 ON tbl.op_order_id = tbl2.order_id AND tbl.op_buyer_id = tbl2.or_buyer_id GROUP BY tbl.op_buyer_id ORDER BY tbl.op_buyer_id
```